# iis htaccess equivalent for re-writing urls

Tags: .htaccess, iis, url-rewriting, web-config

I would like to re-write a URL similar to `domain.com/products.aspx?product=20` into something like `domain.com/products/20`.

Or rather, I'd like to re-write the latter, into the former.

I know how to do this is Apache using `.htaccess` but how would I do it in IIS? I think I need to change the `web.config` file, but what rules would I use?

Any pointers would be greatly appreciated! Thank you!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can find an IIS rewrite module which should do what you want.  You can find it here:
http://www.iis.net/download/urlrewrite

If the link should rot you can find it searching for "IIS url rewrite"

Comment: Instead of posting a link only, you can also include some relevant information at the answers. Links can rot. A better source to refer is http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_rewrite.html

Comment: I get your point... there is a url rewrite module for IIS listed above..  Since you don't want to use apache Rob's link is useless